# How do I use the same render in 2 separate view functions using the if route is condition? (Laravel/Livewire)

Tags: php, view, laravel-blade, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

How do I use the same render in 2 separate view functions using the if route is condition? (Laravel/Livewire)??

I want to render 2 different Livewire.view in the render function by checking the route is same to current route, something like that:

```
public function render()
{
   if (\Route::named('admin-appointments')) {
      return view('livewire.admin-appointments', [
      'data' => $this->read(),
      ]);
   }
   else{
      return view('livewire.user-appointments', [
      'data' => $this->read(),
      ]);
   }
}
```

but I have alwayse problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Making the render depending on the route is unlikely to work. The first request will have the correct route, but all following requests will be triggered by Livewire and not match your route anymore. Instead, you need set a flag while mounting the Livewire component and make your rendering depending on this.

Comment: but I find this in laravel can it help: Accessing The Current Route
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
$route = Route::current(); // Illuminate\Routing\Route
$name = Route::currentRouteName(); // string

Comment: Does this work on subsequent requests? I assume it doesn't leaving your components unable to render correctly.

Comment: yeah I tried it, it works but if i call a specific view it shoes me errors in wich related to the other view!!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you explain this more?